# method polygon_to_cells seems to not exist in H3 library

Tags: python, h3

From the Uber h3 api documentation page (https://uber.github.io/h3-py/api_reference.html#), they have a method called: **polygon_to_cells** which is suppose to transform a given Polygon to a H3 index given a H3 resolution. However, I call this method both in Python (3.6) and from Snowflake UDF (Python 3.9) and in both cases I get the error message back: **module 'h3' has no attribute 'polygon_to_cells'**

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found another documentation that shad the light into the issue (https://nbviewer.org/github/uber/h3-py-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/usage.ipynb).

First I had to do my import as:

```
import h3
h3.polyfill(my_polygon, my_resolution)
```